# How to step through a C program in Anjuta?

Tags: c, anjuta

I need to step through this program, but the icons related to debugging are greyed out, even if I set the configuration to 'debug'. Any idea how this is supposed to work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int number = 7;

  printf ( "%d", number % 2 );
  number = number / 2;
  printf ( "%d", number % 2 );
  number = number / 2;
  printf ( "%d", number % 2 );
  number = number / 2;

  printf ( "\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

OS: Fedora 20

Debugger gdb

I created a general C project (minimal)

Comment: You have given us ZERO information about your platform, compiler, IDE, debugger, .......

Comment: @KevinDTimm Anjuta is an IDE

Comment: i suggest use `qtcreator`

Comment: Have you configured `anjuta` to use `gdb`?

Comment: gdb is listed as installed component and preferred component

Comment: @AlexanderWilms You have to configure your IDE to use `gdb`. There are many other `debuggers`, your IDe needs to know which one to use. Let me install anjuta and try.

Comment: Wow! - Missed it in the title - mea culpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it:

At least there needs to be a Makefile which can be used by gdb. The one created by Anjuta when creating a new C Makefile project can be used as basis.
Also, gdb needs to be enabled in the settings window.

1.Click "Add breakpoint" in the toolbar
2.Execute > Debug program

Then the buttons become sensitive and you can step trough the code